# Avoiding language repetition: grammar still ok?

Tags: grammaticality, repetition

I'm not native, but feel that the following text proposed by my collaborator

> The elements of Pluto are of interest, among other reasons, because
>   Pluto has a large eccentricity, Pluto has a large inclination, and
>   Pluto’s orbit crosses with Neptune’s.

is a bit repetitive and can be improved as

> The elements of Pluto are of interest, among other reasons, because
>   it has a large eccentricity, large inclination, and
>   crosses Neptune’s orbit.

However, my collaborator (an American) argues my change has incorrect grammar and that his original is completely acceptable and fully in line with recommended writing style (he mentions Strunk & White 'Elements of Style').

Is this really so (both incorrect grammar and repetition good style)?

---

**Edit 1** *elements* refers to the orbital elements and is perfectly clear in the context of this sentence. I didn't ask about this.

---

**Edit 2** What about changing *`it`* to *`Pluto`* in my 'improvement' (my actual text communicated to my co-author)? Would that still be grammatical?

Comment: At the very, very, least, try to convince him to replace the last three occurrences of *Pluto* with *it*.

Comment: It would probably be better to replace ***elements*** with something like ***characteristics***. Obviously we are actually interested in the *composition* of Pluto (details of which ***chemical elements*** are present, in what forms), but that's an unwanted allusion in this context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It is referring to "orbital elements", a set of numbers that allow you to calculate the orbit of any astronomical body.

Comment: You should also try to convince him to stop relying on Strunk & White, which is generally [a very poor guide to style](http://www.chronicle.com/article/50-Years-of-Stupid-Grammar/25497). His original here is indeed repetitive and inelegant. Yours is ungrammatical because it contains a list of three things that are not commutable: [has a large eccentricity], [crosses Neptune’s orbit], and [large inclination]. It’s fine if you reduce it to two, though: [has a large eccentricity and inclination] and [crosses Neptune’s orbit].

Comment: One issue that your alteration raises is inconsistent parallelism. Notice that the three branches emerging from "it" in your rewritten wording are "has a large eccentricty" (starts with a verb), "large inclination" (actually branches from "has," not from "it"), and "crosses Neptune' orbit" (starts with a verb). Whether the construction is technically grammatical or not, I wouldn't leave the sentence in that inconsistent, out-of-parallel form.

Comment: Your collaborator is correct. The antecedent for the _it_ would be _elements_, which is plural. It isn't the orbital elements that cross Neptune's orbit, it's Pluto. And repeating it emphasizes Pluto. Which is appropriate in an introduction to something as dry as orbital elements.

Comment: @Mick: If you say so. But taken in isolation it's still something of a garden path statement.

Comment: @John That can be solved by just replacing _it_ with _Pluto_ the once. The original reads like an exercise in extracting antecedents: My brother likes my brother’s tea the way my brother likes my brother’s women: tepid, lemony, and repetitive.

Comment: @JohnLawler How can *it* (singular) refer to *elements* (plural)? It is not obvious that the *only* noun it can (and hence must) refer to is *Pluto*? Btw, my original change had no *it*, but *Pluto* (again).

Comment: @Walter The problem is that _it_ refers back to an entire noun phrase (which is essentially equivalent to its head), and _Pluto_ is not the head of the NP it’s in; _elements_ is. It is clear that _it_ is **supposed** to refer back to _Pluto_, but it doesn’t really work. It is understandable, but it requires a bit of a double-take and jars. It’s like saying, “My aunt’s husband is annoyed because she dented the car”. Clearly, _she_ is supposed to refer back to the aunt, not the husband, but the immediate reaction is, “What? Surely your aunt’s husband is not a she!”

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That example ("My aunt's ...") is IMHO perfectly understandable English and I don't really have your *immediate reaction* at all – does anybody really have that?

Comment: @Walter The immediate reaction is of course not to assume that the speaker’s uncle is transgender. But pronouns in English refer to noun _phrases_, and if there is a discord between the noun phrase and the pronoun, then parsing slows down and a ‘manual’ search for the appropriate antecedent must be undertaken. In some cases we get it with a bit of effort because the pronoun can only fit one element in the discourse; in others it's just unclear (e.g.; “My dad and uncle were regularly spanked when he was still in school”—who does ‘he’ refer to?).

Answer (score 2):

I'll go FumbleFingers one further and argue that you need to rid yourself of *elements* altogether. You're really talking about the ex-planet's orbit:

> Pluto's orbit is interesting because of its large eccentricity, large inclination, and the fact that it crosses with Neptune’s.

If you want to emphasize the fact that you're talking about Pluto, change the subject to Pluto itself and repeat as you feel necessary:

> Pluto is interesting because Pluto's orbit has a large eccentricity, Pluto's orbit has a large inclination, and Pluto’s orbit crosses with Neptune’s.

I don't know why you'd do that, but it's not my paper.

Both your co-author's version and yours are grammatical, but his is odd for the stylistic repetition that seems to have no basis, and yours is jarring because the subject of your sentence is *elements*, which themselves don't cross Neptune's orbit.

I doubt your co-author has read *Elements of Style* in decades.

Comment: I would either include an "its" before "large inclination" in your first revised wording or change the first two entries in the parallel series to a single compound entry (as Janus Bahs Jacquet suggests above): "large orbit and large inclination." And since "large" is arguably being used in two different senses (sheer distance in the first instance and extremity of tilt out of the orbital plane in the second), I would be inclined to change the first occurrence to something like "immense" to give the two modifiers a bit of distance. But I'm copyediting now, aren't I?

Comment: @SvenYargs Well, so you are, but at least it's insightful copyediting. I appreciate that, and I recognize a fellow sufferer of the compulsion to improve a sentence. Keep up the good work.

Comment: Thanks so far. What about my 2nd edit?

Comment: @Walter Your second edit is better because *it* is going to find *interest* as an antecedent.

Comment: My personal preference is to avoid using the phrase "the fact that." In my opinion the phrase is over-used, and in many cases a simple "that" is sufficient to carry the meaning. So, "Pluto's orbit is interesting because of its large eccentricity, large inclination, and that it crosses with Neptune’s." I suppose one could substitute "it" with "its orbit" for slightly better clarity. So, ". . . and that its orbit crosses Neptune's." You'd be surprised, I think, how many decent authors get into the "because of the fact that" habit. Often a simple "because" is sufficient.

Comment: @rhetorician chacun son goût. I prefer *fact* here to make things parallel: *eccentricity, inclination, and fact* instead of *eccentricity, inclination, and it crosses*.

Comment: Fair enough. To be honest, I hadn't thought about how to make the OP's three characteristics parallel to one another. Hmmm. How about "Pluto's orbit is interesting because of its large eccentricity, its large inclination, and its path, which crosses Neptune's"? You've got Pluto's eccentricity, inclination, and path. Sounds parallel to me. Moreover, in this version you've rid the sentence of that annoying  "and the fact that" wordiness. Don